# Is there a standard way to convert a Proc to a Method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there some way to do this in Ruby?:

```
add = lambda { |x, y| x + y }
add_m = add.to_method
add_m(3, 4)
```

Comment: You mean instead of `add_m[3,4]` you want/need to use parentheses?

Comment: exactly. I want `add_m(3, 4)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
add = lambda { |x, y| x + y }
define_singleton_method(:add_m,&add)
p add_m(3,4)
#=> 7
```

Note, however, that you can call a lambda like a method, but with square brackets:

```
add = lambda { |x, y| x + y }
p add[3,4]
#=> 7
```

Comment: Interesting. If there isn't a standard way, I will probably use this.

Comment: @VladtheImpala See my revised answer, using `define_singleton_method`.

Comment: `add.(3, 4)` works, too, assuming a somewhat recent version of Ruby (1.9.0+).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can get exactly that, partly because there is no easy way to get the name of the variable/symbol you are binding to.

The nearest match IMHO:

```
class Proc
   def to_method(m)
     p=self
     Object.class_eval {define_method(m, &p)}     
   end;
 end

 add = lambda { |x, y| x + y }
 add.to_method(:add_m)
 add_m(3, 4)
```

If it's not the Object you want to add the method to, you should pass in the class too.

If syntax doesn't matter too much, you can go with the Phrogz' suggestion: add[3,4],

or just

```
add.call(3,4)
```